# Debug a stored procedure

Tags: sql, debugging, stored-procedures

There is a way to know which function or stored procedure is invoked by a specific stored procedure?

I run want to know what is executed when a complex stored procedure runs.

Thanks!

Comment: You can access the definition of said complex stored procedure, can't you? If not that, and you're wanting to monitor whether a different proc is called, could you alter that one to provide the feedback you seek?

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Depends on the dbms you are using. Some have stored procedure debuggers, others not.